# E_DEVELOPER_ERROR Google is indicating that we have some issue connecting to payment

Tags: typescript, react-native, google-play-billing, react-native-iap

I got an error after using google play subscription in react native using the package `"react-native-iap": "12.10.4",`.

the error i get:
`E_DEVELOPER_ERROR Google is indicating that we have some issue connecting to payment.`

after running into several problems with this package i manage to solve them until i get this error when i try to subscribe using this code:

```
async subscribe(sku: string, offerToken: string) {
    let res = null;

    const init = await initConnection();
    console.log(init);

    try {
      res = await requestSubscription({
        purchaseTokenAndroid: sku,
        subscriptionOffers: [{sku, offerToken}],
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err.code, err.message);
    }

    return res;
  }
```

the sku and offerToken are correct but when i run that code i get the error.

im using an internal testing release and i tried to add my google account to internal testers and to License testing but i get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

i was implementing `requestSubscription()` in a wrong way.

the right way to implement it:

```js
await requestSubscription({
        sku: productId,
        ...(offerToken && {
          subscriptionOffers: [{sku: productId, offerToken}],
        }),
      })
```